# Import CSV to DBeaver: Column names as String --> Mapping not possible

Tags: sql, database, csv, import, dbeaver

I want to import a CSV file into an already existing table in DBeaver.
For this I need to assign the columns. First I set all the columns to skip and then assign them individually. Unfortunately, this mapping does not work because the column names of the CSV file are displayed as a single comma-separated string. How can I import the data successfully?

FYI:

The sql statement:

```
create table bahnhoefe (
  Bundesland varchar(50), 
  RB varchar(10), 
  BM varchar(10), 
  Bf_Nr varchar(10), 
  Station varchar(25), 
  Bf_DS_100Abk varchar(25), 
  Kat_Vst varchar(25), 
  Straße varchar (50), 
  PLZ varchar(5), 
  Ort varchar(25), 
  Aufgabentraeger varchar (50)
)
```

The CSV:
https://download-data.deutschebahn.com/static/datasets/stationsdaten/DBSuS-Uebersicht_Bahnhoefe-Stand2020-03.csv

Comment: Not necessariliy related to your problem, but make sure the fact that the column names contain unicode characters is *not* a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you change the column delimiter at import wizard step 2 :

[image: DBeaver import wizard step 2 with column delimiter set as semicolon]

Please note that you can also easily import a CSV file into a SQLite table with basic command line. For example, having both database and CSV files in the same directory :

```
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .separator ";"
sqlite> .import --skip 1 DBSuS-Uebersicht_Bahnhoefe-Stand2020-03.csv bahnhoefe
sqlite> .mode column
sqlite> select * from bahnhoefe limit 15;
Bundesland  RB        BM         Bf_Nr  Station                Bf_DS_100Abk  Kat_Vst  Straße                 PLZ    Ort                 Aufgabentraeger                  
----------  --------  ---------  -----  ---------------------  ------------  -------  ---------------------  -----  ------------------  ---------------------------------
Hessen      RB Mitte  Darmstadt  119    Altheim (Hess)         FAT           6        Münstererstr. 19       64839  Münster             Rhein-Main-Verkehrsverbund GmbH  
Hessen      RB Mitte  Darmstadt  201    Assmannshausen         FAH           5        Bahnhofstr. 1          65385  Rüdesheim am Rhein  Rhein-Main-Verkehrsverbund GmbH  
Hessen      RB Mitte  Darmstadt  230    Auringen-Medenbach     FAM           6        August-Ruf-Straße 50   65207  Wiesbaden           Rhein-Main-Verkehrsverbund GmbH  
Hessen      RB Mitte  Darmstadt  238    Babenhausen (Hess)     FBA           5        Am Bahnhof 1           64832  Babenhausen         Rhein-Main-Verkehrsverbund GmbH  
Hessen      RB Mitte  Darmstadt  3564   Babenhausen Langstadt  FLAS          7        Kleestädter-Str. 75    64832  Babenhausen         Rhein-Main-Verkehrsverbund GmbH  
Hessen      RB Mitte  Darmstadt  292    Bad König              FKI           6        Bahnhofsplatz 1        64732  Bad König           Rhein-Main-Verkehrsverbund GmbH  
Hessen      RB Mitte  Darmstadt  6989   Bad König-Zell         FZK           7        An der alten Schule 5  64732  Bad König           Rhein-Main-Verkehrsverbund GmbH  
Hessen      RB Mitte  Darmstadt  2753   Beerfelden-Hetzbach    FHZ           6        Bahnhofstr. 45         64743  Beerfelden          Rhein-Main-Verkehrsverbund GmbH  
Hessen      RB Mitte  Darmstadt  488    Bensheim               FBH           4        Amershamplatz 1        64625  Bensheim            Verkehrsverbund Rhein-Neckar GmbH
Hessen      RB Mitte  Darmstadt  489    Bensheim-Auerbach      FBAU          5        Otto-Beck-Str. 32      64625  Bensheim            Verkehrsverbund Rhein-Neckar GmbH
Hessen      RB Mitte  Darmstadt  614    Biblis                 FBL           4        Lindenstr. 2           68647  Biblis              Verkehrsverbund Rhein-Neckar GmbH
Hessen      RB Mitte  Darmstadt  618    Bickenbach (Bergstr)   FBI           5        Bahnhofstr. 77         64404  Bickenbach          Rhein-Main-Verkehrsverbund GmbH  
Hessen      RB Mitte  Darmstadt  619    Biebesheim             FBBM          5        Eisenbahnstr. 8        64585  Biebesheim          Rhein-Main-Verkehrsverbund GmbH  
Hessen      RB Mitte  Darmstadt  721    Bobstadt               FBST          6        Bergstr.45A            68642  Bürstadt            Verkehrsverbund Rhein-Neckar GmbH
Hessen      RB Mitte  Darmstadt  1002   Bürstadt               FBUE          6        Bahnhofsallee 17       68642  Bürstadt            Verkehrsverbund Rhein-Neckar GmbH
```

You can refer to the [SQLite documentation](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#importing_files_as_csv_or_other_formats) for further details.